# MUltile file upload in laravel

Tags: laravel, database, performance, optimization, file-upload

```
public function store(StoreWorkerRequest $request)
{
    $attributes = $request->validated();

    $worker = DB::transaction(function () use ($attributes, $request) {
        $worker = Worker::create($attributes);
        $course = $worker->course()->create(['course_name' => $attributes['course_name']]);
        $medical_data = $worker->medical_detail()->create(['expiry_date' => $attributes['expiry_date']]);
        $document = $worker->document()->create(['doc_name' => $attributes['doc_name']]);
        if($request->file('doc_files' || 'media_files' || 'user_files'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('doc_files') as $image)
            {
                $document = $document->media()->create(["filename" => 
          fileUpload($image, 'Course'),"filetype" => "pdf"]);
            }
        foreach($request->file('media_files') as $image)
            {
                $course = $course->media()->create(["filename" => 
               fileUpload($image, 'Course'),"filetype" => "pdf"]);
            }
          foreach($request->file('user_files') as $image)
            {
                $media = $user->media()->create(["filename" => 
            fileUpload($image, 'Course'),"filetype" => "pdf"]);
            }
        }
        return $worker;
    });
```

This is my multiple file upload in laravel, But the problem in, I have three fields that have multiple file (`media_files, doc_files, user_files`). Problem is I cannot repeat the same foreach loop for every files_attributes. (like I can't heck `if($request->file('doc_file'))` for media_files user _files, repeating the same foreach loop again and again. How can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop over `$request->file()` and perform your upload based on that:

```php
foreach($request->file() as $key => $files) {
  foreach ($files as $image) {
    if ($key == 'media_files') {
      $course->media()->create(['filename' => fileUpload($image, 'Course'), 'filetype' => 'pdf']);
    } elseif ($key == 'doc_files') {
      $document->media()->create(['filename' => fileUpload($image, 'Course'), 'filetype' => 'pdf']);
    } elseif ($key == 'user_files') {
      $user->media()->create(['filename' =>  fileUpload($image, 'Course'), 'filetype' => 'pdf']);
    }   
  }
}
```

You may need to use `'doc_file'` instead of `'doc_files'` depending on if your names are singular or plural, but the approach should still work.

Comment: Thank you but this is not either case, if all `media_files, doc_files user_files` are coming I am storing all of them. NOt actually either or case

Comment: Then ignore the `if()`/`elseif()` statements. The `foreach()` loop is still what you'd use to avoid writing `if($request->file('doc_file'))` and `foreach($request->file('doc_file') as $file)`.

Comment: I dont know MIght be I am not getting `foreach($request->file('doc_file') as $image)` This is how I have loped over the images,   This loops over the every single images of array doct_file? Same way I need to do `foreach($request->file('media_files') as $image)` to loop over the media files and  same for user_files. Differently? which means 3 loops.

Comment: That's why there's 2 nested `foreach` loops...; the first is `foreach($request->files() as $key => $files)`; `$key` is `media_file`, then `doc_file` then `user_file`, the second is `foreach($files as $file)` (or `$image`; whatever you want to call it).

Comment: Look at my code now; I've reduced your 3 `if()`/`foreach()` loops into 2 nested `foreach()` loops, with an `if()` statement based on the `$key`.

Comment: Got this, but nested foreach causes `O(n²)` complexity. Is there any oter alernative?

Comment: That feels pretty irrelevant for 3 iterations of `N` files, plus 3 individual `if()`/`foreach()` isn't really any less complex... but, if you're concerned about execution complexity over code functionality and readability, please consider deleting the question and re-posting it over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.